# Failed to remote debug Dot Net 6.0 C# console application into Raspberry Pi 4 machine usnig Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, debian, raspberry-pi4

I am facing the issue while remote debugging on Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian or Linux Environment). I have a Dot Net 6.0 C# based console application. I wanted to debug in Linux machine line by line. I have installed all the necessary files or library on linux machine. When I have coped the Bin folder and execute manually on Linux machine in that case its executed successfully, but I wanted to remote debug the application. I have configured the debug setting as below link

“Debug .NET Core on Linux using SSH by attaching to a process.”

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2022

When I have attached the Process  to -  Automatically then Debug code Type is Managed (.Net Core for Linux). I am getting the error as below :

“Microsoft Visual Studio Failed to launch debug adapter.  Additional information may be available in the output window. Unable to find debugger script at '/home/admin/.vs-debugger'.”

[image]

Error when Press the Attach Button :

[image]

My project launchSettings.json file as below :

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "LIBUSBExample": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "/home/admin/.vs-debugger",
      "workingDirectory": "bin\\",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "admin": "admin"
      },
      "remoteDebugEnabled": true,
      "remoteDebugMachine": "192.168.0.229",
      "authenticationMode": "Windows",
      "nativeDebugging": true
    },
    "WSL": {
      "commandName": "WSL2",
      "distributionName": ""
    }
  }
```

My Project debugg setting as below :

[image]

**Added the PDB file screenshot. Its in the same folder where exe "bin\ARM\debug.net6.0"**

[image]

Comment: Does you project have a debug folder with the pdb file?  The pdb file contains debug info needed for the debugger to work.  The working folder in windows is usually bin\debug not just bin.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. No, How to create pdb file with debug info. and where and how it configure ?

Comment: I have added the current pdb file location as "LIBUSBExample\bin\ARM64\Debug\net6.0". Where it should be located ?

Comment: The pdb file should be in the bin\debug folder.  The main folder is where the csproj file and the source c# files are located.  The location of the bin folder isn't important as long as the dlls and pdb files are colocated.